# Excluding files when checking out from Subversion repository

Tags: svn

I work with a subversion repository for a "generic" package that is full of files that shouldn't be there (site-specific files, hacks, etc). I do not have access to change this, and I've been stonewalled when I ask about having it changed on my behalf; I'm now after a workaround.

Is it possible to exclude some files from being checked out (or being pulled out of the repository when updating), so that I can work with some semblance of a clean package?

These files are independent and are not being pulled in by the other "good" files, so there aren't any dependency problems in that regard.

*(Please note this is not the usual "How do I stop files from being committed" question answered by svn:ignore. Sorry. :-) )*

Comment: If you have commit access why don't you have access to commit a revision with them deleted or moved?

Comment: Ideally, you'll probably want them in branches, so main code line remains clean?

Comment: They may be in a part of the project that he doesn't have commit access too. SVN permissions are pretty granular if you want them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get this straight:

- That these files are checked in is an obvious error.
- You have the access privilege necessary to remove them, but you have to ask whether you are allowed to exercise your access privilege.
- You are forbidden to do a necessary change.

Did I sum up this right?

If I did, then I see two possible reasons for your problem:

1. You are wrong regarding the issue.
2. You are on the wrong job or in the wrong company.

I don't think SVN has a way to fix the problems arising from either of these reasons. (FWIW, I agree with the other answers that it doesn't even have the means to *work around* them.) To fix this, you would, in the first case, need to have someone explain it to you. (If they won't, see #2.) In the second case, get another job. Soon.

Answer (score 2):

[Sparse directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) *may* help.